# MySQL not null constraint doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I Have Created one table that is Employee table (

```
create table person(
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| p_id   | int(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| p_name | var char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| p_add  | var char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| p_mob  | int(10)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

while during insertion if i write query like .

```
insert into employee values ('1','','','');
+------+--------+-------+-----------+
| p_id | p_name | p_add | p_mob     |
+------+--------+-------+-----------+
|    1 |        |       | 908765432 |
|    2 |        |       |        90 |
+------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

and if i left all the rest column blank then it must gives some error,because I have written in my query these all column as Not Null but why still it insert the null that is blank ,whether i was trying same code  in oracle then it was working . Is there any problem  with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can attach some code, the explaination is hard to understand. (I think you got confused with the table names too, `person` vs `employee`) What i think you want is:

```
insert into employee values ('1',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, empty string and `NULL` are the same thing.  However, in MySQL empty string is a string value, not `NULL`.  Hence, in MySQL your not null constraints are never preventing the insertion of the following record:

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('1', '', '', '');
```

The following insert *would* fail:

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('1', NULL, '', '');
```

If you need a way to cleanly handle `NULL` and empty string as the same thing in MySQL, you can use `COALESCE(column, '')` and compare it to empty string.